# Android player which support Wowza (RTSP/RTMP) Audio streaming

Tags: android, audio-streaming, rtsp, rtmp

Is there any best way to run audio Wowza (RTSP/RTMP) on Android with all API Level i.e at-least from Api level 14 and later.

**I have tried**

> 1. vitamio library :

but it was not working on Api 23 which is really very
    strange case.

> 2. ExoPlayer :

but it is not playing my text audio url

and tested many other players too.

> Test URL :

**RTMP -** rtmp://10.10.3.11:1935/vod/mp3:01 - Aankhon Mein(MyMp3Song.Com)-1466059658085.mp3

**RTSP -** rtsp://10.10.3.11:1935/vod/mp3:01 - Aankhon Mein(MyMp3Song.Com)-1466059658085.mp3

If someone has done this please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: the default video view only is capable of playing

Comment: @war_Hero can you please share me any example link.. because I have done so much RND.. but no luck.

Comment: that might be because the url which you are trying might be old or broken

Comment: http://www.vlc.eu.pn/index.php it has a lot some might be old/broken infact in exo player you have various links in the demo app

Comment: @war_Hero the audio link is working in vitamio library but below API 23